# Iterating through list of <div> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery to iterate through a list of `<div>`s in the following example:

```
<div id="selectedDefinitionsDiv">
    <div id="selectedDef1" class="myclass">
        <textarea class="textClass" style="margin-left:5px;width:600px;height:80px;">an adoptive country</textarea>
        <input type="button" onclick="removeSelectedDefinition(1)" value="Delete">
    </div>
    <div id="selectedDef2" class="myclass">
        <textarea class="textClass" style="margin-left:5px;width:600px;height:80px;">my adopted state</textarea>
        <input type="button" onclick="removeSelectedDefinition(2)" value="Delete">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pull out the data in each of the textareas. In the above example that would be  `an adoptive country` **and** `my adopted state`

I have tried

```
$(#selectedDefinitionsDiv).children('myclass').each(function(i) { 
    var val = $(this).children('textClass').value;
    processString( val );
});
```

But it doesn't go into the loop at all. Any idea what is wrong with my jQuery?

Comment: please try to put quotes around the selector and use proper selectors, that is probably your problem here.

Comment: see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhGbP/) to your proper requirement, and also try to look more into [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/) for proper selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing code you will probably be getting a JavaScript error since the syntax is illegal. This explains why the code is not executing. The illegal syntax is that

```
$(#selectedDefinitionsDiv)
```

is missing the surrounding quotes like so `$('#selectedDefinitionsDiv')`.

However, whilst that fixes the syntax error, there are further problems with the selectors.

The CSS class selector in the second and third selectors `children('myclass')` and `.children('textClass')` is missing the leading `.` - it should be `.myclass` and `.textClass` and you need to use jQuery's `.val()` instead of the plain JavaScript `.value` since the object you are calling `.value` on is a jQuery object.

A simpler solution would be to just supply a more specific selector:

```
$('#selectedDefinitionsDiv .textClass').each(function(i) {  
    var val = $(this).val();
    processString(val);
});​
```

Comment: Kudos to Avinash  as well but this one appears to be a more refined answer.  Thnx

Answer (score 3):

Quotes missing in selector

**Change**

```
$(#selectedDefinitionsDiv)
```

**to**

```
$("#selectedDefinitionsDiv")
```

*Also change value to val() and add . before class name in selector*

```
$("#selectedDefinitionsDiv").children('.myclass').each(function(i) { 
    var val = $(this).children('.textClass').val();
    processString( val );
});
```

On more thing closing `>` of first div

**[Live Demo on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uselaf/1/edit)**

**[Live Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/y3Gsu/)**

Comment: Sorry,  that was a typo on my part.  Still missing something

Comment: On more thing closing > of first div

Comment: I have added a link of live domo, you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/y3Gsu/

Answer (score 2):

1. You need  quotes:    $("#selectedDefinitionsDiv")
2. Instead value, you need to use val()

Answer (score 1):

Just looks to need a bit of tidy up - `myclass` needs to be prefixed with a `.` and the `id` need to be in quotes.

`children('.textClass')` also needs a `.` prefix:

```
$("#selectedDefinitionsDiv").children(".myclass").each(function(i)
{
   var val = $(this).children('.textClass').val();
   processString( val );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').each(function(i) { 
    var val = $(this).val();
    processString( val );
});
```

Hope this helps.